# drupal could not index site using apache solr

Tags: search

I'm using windows 8,and have installed apache solr(version 4.4.0) using BitNami installer,I've install "search api" and "search api solr" modules on my drupal7 site,then I add solr server to module and the connection has made successfully, the problem is when I'm trying to index my site using the default "Default node index" index I get "Couldn't index items. Check the logs for details."

I've replace the files in "search_api_solr\solr-conf\4.x" folder of search api solr module into "C:\solr\apache-solr\solr\collection1\conf"

the drupal log message is :

> SearchApiException while indexing: "400" Status: Bad Request: Bad Request{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":1},"error":{"msg":"ERROR: [doc=default_node_index-1] unknown field 'index_id'","code":400}} in `SearchApiSolrConnection->checkResponse()` (line 548 of C:\wamp1\www\testak\sites\all\modules\search_api_solr\includes\solr_connection.inc).

and in my solr log I have :

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=default_node_index-1] unknown field 'index_id'

i don't get what did i miss

this is my schema :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!--
 This is the Solr schema file. This file should be named "schema.xml" and
 should be in the conf directory under the solr home
 (i.e. ./solr/conf/schema.xml by default)
 or located where the classloader for the Solr webapp can find it.

 For more information, on how to customize this file, please see
 http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml
-->

<schema name="drupal-4.1-solr-4.x" version="1.3">

  <types>

    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldtype name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>
    <fieldType name="integer" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.TrieIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="slong" class="solr.TrieFloatField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sfloat" class="solr.TrieLongField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="pfloat" class="solr.FloatField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="file" keyField="id" defVal="1" stored="false" indexed="false" class="solr.ExternalFileField" valType="pfloat"/>
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                protected="protwords.txt"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1"
                catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="1"
                preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                protected="protwords.txt"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="1"
                preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="text_und" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                protected="protwords.txt"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1"
                catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                protected="protwords.txt"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="edge_n2_kw_text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="25" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="4" max="20" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="sortString" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        -->
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="rand" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />
    <fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" class="solr.StrField" />
    <fieldType name="point" class="solr.PointType" dimension="2" subFieldType="tdouble"/>
    <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldType="tdouble"/>
    <fieldtype name="geohash" class="solr.GeoHashField"/>
  </types>

  <xi:include href="schema_extra_types.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xi:fallback></xi:fallback>
  </xi:include>

  <fields>
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="item_id"  type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="index_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <copyField source="item_id" dest="sort_search_api_id" />
    <field name="entity_id"  type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="entity_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="bundle" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="bundle_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="site" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="hash" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="url" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="label" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <copyField source="label" dest="sort_label"/>

    <field name="content" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true"/>
    <field name="teaser" type="text" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
    <field name="path" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="path_alias" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <field name="tid"  type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="taxonomy_names" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" termVectors="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <copyField source="tm_vid_*" dest="taxonomy_names"/>
    <field name="timestamp" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="spell" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <copyField source="label" dest="spell"/>
    <copyField source="content" dest="spell"/>

    <copyField source="ts_*" dest="spell"/>
    <copyField source="tm_*" dest="spell"/>
    <dynamicField name="tags_*" type="text"   indexed="true" stored="false" omitNorms="true"/>

    <dynamicField name="is_*"  type="long"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="im_*"  type="long"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="fs_*"  type="float"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="fm_*"  type="float"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="ps_*"  type="double"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="pm_*"  type="double"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="bm_*"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="bs_*"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="ss_*"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="sm_*"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="ts_*"  type="text"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="tm_*"  type="text"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="tus_*" type="text_und" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="tum_*" type="text_und" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="tos_*" type="text"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="tom_*" type="text"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="tes_*" type="edge_n2_kw_text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />
    <dynamicField name="tem_*" type="edge_n2_kw_text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />
    <dynamicField name="tws_*" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="twm_*" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

    <dynamicField name="ds_*"  type="tdate"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="dm_*"  type="tdate"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="its_*" type="tlong"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="itm_*" type="tlong"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="fts_*" type="tfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="ftm_*" type="tfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="pts_*" type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="ptm_*" type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

    <dynamicField name="xs_*"  type="binary"  indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="xm_*"  type="binary"  indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="dds_*" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="ddm_*" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

    <dynamicField name="iss_*" type="slong"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="ism_*" type="slong"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="fss_*" type="sfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="fsm_*" type="sfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="pss_*" type="sdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="psm_*" type="sdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="hs_*" type="integer" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="hm_*" type="integer" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="hss_*" type="sint"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="hsm_*" type="sint"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="hts_*" type="tint"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="htm_*" type="tint"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

    <dynamicField name="zs_*" type="string"   indexed="false"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="zm_*" type="string"   indexed="false"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="points_*" type="point" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="pointm_*" type="point" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="locs_*" type="location" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="locm_*" type="location" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="geos_*" type="geohash" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="geom_*" type="geohash" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

    <dynamicField name="eff_*" type="file"/>

    <dynamicField name="sort_*" type="sortString" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
    <copyField source="ss_*" dest="sort_*"/>
    <dynamicField name="random_*" type="rand" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  </fields>

  <xi:include href="schema_extra_fields.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xi:fallback></xi:fallback>
  </xi:include>

  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

  <defaultSearchField>content</defaultSearchField>

  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>

</schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache solr was configured properly, but the modules I've installed facing some problem though, I reinstalled the **Search api** and **Search api Solr** module and it solved the problem.